# Listing audio files with bit rate in the command line

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to list the contents of a folder via the command line in such a way that the audio files in mp3 format have the bit rate info? I tried `ls -l` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `find <music_dir> -exec exiftool -AudioBitrate {}\;` may do what you want if you have `exiftool` installed.

Comment: I don't and it's not in the Fedora's repos.

Comment: Sorry, `exiftool` is indeed in the Fedora Repos. Already installed it, and your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

With `find` and `file`:

```
find Music/Albert\ Ayler/Vibrations/ -name "*.flac" -exec file {} \;
Music/Albert Ayler/Vibrations/1.Ghosts.flac: FLAC audio bitstream data, 16 bit, stereo, 44.1 kHz, 5653620 samples
Music/Albert Ayler/Vibrations/4.Ghosts (2).flac: FLAC audio bitstream data, 16 bit, stereo, 44.1 kHz, 21096264 samples
Music/Albert Ayler/Vibrations/3.Holy Spirit.flac: FLAC audio bitstream data, 16 bit, stereo, 44.1 kHz, 22529220 samples
Music/Albert Ayler/Vibrations/5.Vibrations.flac: FLAC audio bitstream data, 16 bit, stereo, 44.1 kHz, 13225296 samples
Music/Albert Ayler/Vibrations/2.Children.flac: FLAC audio bitstream data, 16 bit, stereo, 44.1 kHz, 18213300 samples
Music/Albert Ayler/Vibrations/6.Mothers.flac: FLAC audio bitstream data, 16 bit, stereo, 44.1 kHz, 18814824 samples
```

You could further filter the output depending upon the fields you are interested in...

Comment: Nothing gets returned with this command.

Comment: Are your audio files in the flac format? If not, then no, this command won't return anything. You would need to replace the `"*.flac"` with the extensions of the files that you are interested in. E.g. if they end in mp3, then you would replace `"*.flac"` with `"*.mp3"` etc.

Comment: @CarlVidal Did you adapt it for your needs? There is no reason it shouldn't work if it is pointed at the right directory. Change (or remove) the `-name "*.flac"` if necessary...

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the asterisk. Now it returns some additional info about the files ("Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0") but not the bit rate. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: @CarlVidal No: you'll need to edit your question and include information about the type of files you are working with.